# Log Data transform script in R acting "wonky"

Tags: r, matrix, transformation, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a small script that will create log transforms of the absolute value of my data, but when the original value is zero (`ln(0)==Inf`) return the minimum log value of all the other values in the column.

Here is the example data and code:

```
bogusdata <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,0,-1,-0.25,0,-2,0,-1,-0.5), nrow=7, ncol=2)
colnames(bogusdata)<- c("X","Y")
original.columns <- as.vector(colnames(bogusdata))
for (i in 1:length(original.columns))
{
temp <- as.matrix(bogusdata[,i])
ind <- which(temp[i]==0)
temp[ind] <- NA
temp.log <- log(abs(temp))
min.log <- temp.log[which.min(temp.log)]
temp.log[ind] <- min.log
bogusdata <- cbind(bogusdata, temp.log)
colnames(bogusdata)[length(original.columns)+i] <- paste("L.",original.columns[i], sep="")
}
```

The output is:

```
> bogusdata
     X     Y       L.X        L.Y
[1,] 1 -1.00 0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,] 2 -0.25 0.6931472 -1.3862944
[3,] 3  0.00 1.0986123       -Inf
[4,] 4 -2.00 1.3862944  0.6931472
[5,] 5  0.00 1.6094379       -Inf
[6,] 6 -1.00 1.7917595  0.0000000
[7,] 0 -0.50      -Inf -0.6931472
```

I **intended** the output to be:

```
> bogusdata
     X     Y       L.X        L.Y
[1,] 1 -1.00 0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,] 2 -0.25 0.6931472 -1.3862944
[3,] 3  0.00 1.0986123 -1.3862944
[4,] 4 -2.00 1.3862944  0.6931472
[5,] 5  0.00 1.6094379 -1.3862944
[6,] 6 -1.00 1.7917595  0.0000000
[7,] 0 -0.50 0.0000000 -0.6931472
```

I *think* my error is in the `ind` variable, as it doesn't seem to be functioning properly:

```
> ind
integer(0)
```

Which makes no sense at all to me. Clearly `temp[i]==0` for certain cells... but `ind` isn't catching them.

P.S. This can probably also be done with `is.infinite()`, but let's call this a learning exercise. I'd like to understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coding error is here:

```
temp <- as.matrix(bogusdata[,i])
ind <- which(temp[i]==0)
```

you are using the `i` index twice inapproriatly. you extract the `temp` matrix for only the column you are interested in, but then you only look at the `i`th element in that list. You really want just

```
temp <- as.matrix(bogusdata[,i])
ind <- which(temp==0)
```

I might also consider writing a transformation function

```
trans<-function(x) 
    ifelse(x==0, min(log(abs(x[x!=0]))), log(abs(x)))
```

and then apply that do your data column-wise

```
newcols <- apply(bogusdata,2,trans)
colnames(newcols) <- paste0("L.", colnames(bogusdata))

cbind(bogusdata, newcols)
```

which returns

```
     X     Y       L.X        L.Y
[1,] 1 -1.00 0.0000000  0.0000000
[2,] 2 -0.25 0.6931472 -1.3862944
[3,] 3  0.00 1.0986123 -1.3862944
[4,] 4 -2.00 1.3862944  0.6931472
[5,] 5  0.00 1.6094379 -1.3862944
[6,] 6 -1.00 1.7917595  0.0000000
[7,] 0 -0.50 0.0000000 -0.6931472
```

Comment: Wonderful! It is easy to see once someone points it out, but I sure was having trouble finding the issue. Good idea on the function call. Much simpler. I'll use that instead. :-)